# What is the possessive form of “neither”?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, neither-nor, indefinite-pronouns

I’m working on a worksheet and it’s telling me to make up a sentence using the possessive form of the indefinite pronoun *neither.* It says to use apostrophes on all these pronouns to make them possessive but *neither’s* doesn’t seem like a word I could properly use in a sentence.

Am I correct and what is the correct possessive form?

Comment: Yep, "neither's" is correct.  It is awkward enough, however, that folks tend to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition has misled you. The possessive of *neither* is formed in the ordinary way. [Here's](https://books.google.com/books?id=hyo2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22neither%27s%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwsq68-c7QAhXBTSYKHc8mDfgQ6AEIMzAF#v=onepage&q=%22neither's%22&f=false) a nice example:

> **Neither's** opinion was expressed in public ; **neither's** was known to the other....

Comment: I suspect most people would say *neither one’s opinion* or *neither opinion*.